# How can I convert dates properly so that i can execute described oracle query?

Tags: oracle

```
fdayp = "2018-04-18 00:00:00.0" 
and tdaym= "2017-10-20 00:00:00.0" 
and start_date = "18-Jan-2018".
```

I got failed to execute this query-

```
select count(*)from a_detail 
where start_date BETWEEN '2018-04-18 00:00:00.0' and '2017-10-20 00:00:00.0' 
and emp_id='703301' ;
```

Comment: You forgot to enter line breaks and formatting into your question.

Comment: how can i compare these two dates?? fdayp = "2018-04-18 00:00:00.0"  and from = "18-Jan-2018".

Comment: Please try to simplify and better format your question. If the issue is in the Oracle part, please remove the Java part and simply post the query you're trying to write, as formatted text

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use dates you can simply use the ANSI format for dates (with no hours, minutes, seconds):

```
select count(*)
from a_detail
where start_date BETWEEN date '2017-10-20' and date '2018-04-18'
```

Also, please pay attention to the order you use the dates in `BETWEEN`: the parameters must be `begin date` , `end date`.